# VBA for extracting Data from URL

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to get some data from google map with VBA to extract in to excel. as I am not expert in VBA so facing some problem. in side google map, if we scroll to down there are some web result links coming in script. I want to extract that link if possible.  here I try from my end but not getting actually result what I want

here is screen shot for web result of google map url

[image]

also here I some code which I try but not success

```
        Public Sub GmapData()

            'On Error Resume Next

            Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            ie.Visible = True
            
            ie.navigate "https://g.page/MiguelLopezSalon?share" ' try with first URLS and second
            Do
            DoEvents
            Loop Until ie.readystate <> 4
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))
            
            Dim MyData As New MSForms.DataObject
            MyData.GetFromClipboard
           
            
            
            For N = 0 To ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text gm2-body-2").Length - 1
               
            If ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text gm2-body-2").Item(N).innerText = "About this data" Then
                 ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text gm2-body-2").Item(N).ScrollIntoView (False)
            End If
            
            
            Next N

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

                  
                  GMD = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("trex").Item(0).innerHTML  ' facing error here
                  
                  ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = GMD
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Which link? Just one link? The first?

Answer (score 0):

I try to google on my issue.. then found its a iframe  inside html.. also try with following code line but still not get result

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).document.getElementsByClassName("trex").Item(0).innerHTML
```

Please anyone can me help out.  to extract data within Ifram